# Redux: Is it necessary?

Tags: state, reactjs

Is a reducer like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) really necessary when developing with [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/)?
Is it just a way to design cleaner code?
If so, when?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, reducers or Redux are not necessary. Vanilla React works fine, or other options, e.g. MobX.

Check out the [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#general-when-to-use):

> Dan Abramov, one of the creators of Redux, says:
>
> ...don’t use Redux until you have problems with vanilla React.

When to use Redux is an architectural opinion and the FAQ provides this guideline:

> In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React component’s state are no longer sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

React is just a library to build UI. Not an entire framework. Using redux let you handle all the logic of your application in a clean way. There are other library similar to redux, but redux seems to be the way to go when starting a new project with react.

Answer (score -4):

Short answer you do not have to use Redux but it is considerably easier on you if you do chose to use it, there is a lot of examples online which i can point you at where you can learn how Redux and React work. Note that React is only V(view layer) in MVC that being said react does one job and it does it really good that is displaying user interface.

Comment: Facebook employees don't agree React is necessarily just V in MVC, see https://rationaldev.com/react-is-not-just-the-v-in-mvc/

Comment: The question was not about MVC and you did not answer why Redux is not necessary